# Using CASE outside SELECT in table-valued function

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to select the same columns from a different table/view depending on the value of an argument (@ruleset). As it is not possible to pass the name of the table as a parameter nor to construct the name inside the function, used CASE structure outside the select statements. However, I get an error:
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."
[Hope I get this right, it is my first question here.]

```
CREATE FUNCTION app.fgProduct 
(   
    @ruleset nvarchar(50),
    @matno nvarchar(50), 
    @datarevision int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT
CASE WHEN @ruleset = 'G1' THEN 
(
  SELECT 
    @matno AS ProductId
    ,@datarevision AS DataRevision
    ,[ProductName]
  FROM [ruleset].[g1gxProduct]
  WHERE ProductId = @matno
)
WHEN @ruleset = 'G2' THEN 
(
  SELECT 
    @matno AS ProductId
    ,@datarevision AS DataRevision
    ,[ProductName]
  FROM [ruleset].[g2gxProduct]
  WHERE ProductId = @matno
)
END
)
```

There's a bunch of other views, so this whole issue cannot be solved in one procedure. Above is an example of a function which is used to generate new records based on various rule sets (= sets of views).

Comment: I think you are trying to do an `IF` control flow mechanic inside a `SELECT`, which is not meant to be that way. Declare the resulting table and insert into it with an actual IF. If you want an in-line TVF then you will have to do a full join and validate the row in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks @EzLo for a valuable comment! That was the key to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to declare a result table and insert into it, just like @EzLo suggested in the comment.

```
CREATE FUNCTION app.fgProduct 
(   
  @ruleset nvarchar(50),
  @matno nvarchar(50), 
  @datarevision int
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE (
  [ProductID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [DataRevision] [int] NOT NULL,
  [ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
IF @ruleset = 'G1'
  INSERT INTO @ret 
  SELECT 
    @matno AS ProductId
    ,@datarevision AS DataRevision
    ,[ProductName]
  FROM [ruleset].[g1gxProduct]
  WHERE ProductId = @matno
ELSE
IF @ruleset = 'G2'
  INSERT INTO @ret 
  SELECT 
    @matno AS ProductId
    ,@datarevision AS DataRevision
    ,[ProductName]
  FROM [ruleset].[g2gxProduct]
  WHERE ProductId = @matno
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an expression and not for conditional flow. Use `IF`/`ELSE` instead.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However, IF/ELSE couldn't be used in a plain table-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the select statements that are returning more than one column in the sub query. You can only return one column in the statements:

```
SELECT 
    @matno AS ProductId
    ,@datarevision AS DataRevision
    ,[ProductName]
```